# Duplicating a content type form in SP Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, content-type

When i create a new form in SP Designer i am given the option to select the content type to use.  My assumption is that when you select the content type that it will use that as the parent to create the new form.  I.e. it will copy the fields and order them as they are laid out in that content type.  I was also thinking that when using the form to submit a new item that it would show that it was submitting using that content type, but this is not the case.

What i'm experiencing is that if i select a content type on the Create New List Form screen (pictured below), it doesn't appear to do anything.  It still uses the default content type to construct the form.  When i submit using the form it lists the content type as the default and not the one i selected when i created the form.

Is this how it's supposed to function?  And if so, what's the point of having this option?  It doesn't appear that it does anything.  I've ran into this issue several times when wanting to make a new form based on one i already had setup as a content type, but couldn't do so unless it was the default content type.  I usually end up having to delete and reorder the fields in the code in order to structure the fields back to how i want them in the form.  This works in some instances, but in some cases i'm using the content type to populate a hidden field so that i can later filter and sort based on which form they use.  Am i going about this all wrong?  Is there an easier way to duplicate a content type form to create a new one?  Am i not understanding how this is supposed to function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those maddening "stupid SharePoint" moments.  Try starting by creating custom Display forms and use the "Create link in List Item Menu" option, double-check those in the browser, THEN it should let you create new/edit forms based on your content types. However, whichever form is marked as default in Designer will still be what's used when you click New Item or Edit Item. To get this to work on a list where I had already customized forms, I had to delete all of them before starting over with the display forms.

Comment: I tried this and it's still just dumping all the fields in the form.  I previously thought that it was copying the default content type, but upon further inspection it's actually just adding all the fields in the list into the form. Maybe i'm not doing it the same way as you?  I went into Lists and Libraries > clicked on the list i wanted > Clicked New in the forms section.

Comment: I did it in SharePoint Designer. Lists and Libraries > My List > Forms > New Form.  At first mine behaved as you described, but after I fiddled with it for a while it started limiting the fields. So I created a brand new list, started with 2 display forms (one for each of my content types),  then built new and edit forms. Then I went back to my first list, deleted all my custom forms, and started over with display and it worked.